# How to use proguard to remove unused resources in android support v*

Tags: android, proguard

I tried to proguard my project using: `minifyEnabled true` `shrinkResources true`
But I found it cound not remove unused resources in android support v* like these:
`anim\` `anim-v21\` `animator-v21\` `color\`
and so on
I think I did not use these, can anyone tell me how to remove it?